# What is the purpose of the "System" User?

Tags: system-admin, system

There's lot of information about the *Automated Process User* in Salesforce where it's used to make [automated system-level changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339878&type=1&mode=1) by Salesforce.

However, I noticed that we also had a user called *System* that is similarly inaccessible like *Automated Process*.

I can query the user in SOQL to get the userId but I'm not able to view the full user details in the UI and it shares the same ProfileId as the *Automated User*.

```
SELECT Id,ProfileId FROM User WHERE Name = 'System' OR Name = 'Automated Process'
```

The email contains `automatedcase@[ourORGID].ext` and the only scenario I see with a reference to the user is under `Support Settings` where you can select the `Automated Case User` to be `System`. Weirdly, the Salesforce doc on [Automated Case User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326328&type=1&mode=1) only mentions the ability to select a user through the lookup (and makes no mention of the dropdown to select "System").

[image]

However, this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_supportrules.htm&type=5) does make mention of the above selection for *System*, but the reasoning seems like it oddly could've been handled by the "Automated Process" user since it's to indicate an automated process.

[image]

That may be its only purpose, but I'm having a hard time finding any information on this user otherwise  - most likely due to the fact that the name "System" is a little non-specific. I see the following [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lFGpQAM) that mentions the user being invisible to sharing rules which again is related to the Automated Case User workflow above.

We do not use this user as the Automated Case User so **is there no other purpose or documentation concerning usage for this user?** Is it right to assume *Automated Process user* handles "other" system-level changes while this *System* user is only concerning automation on cases?

Comment: which user executes background roll-up summaries or recalculation of sharing rules?